# Elmah mvc BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, error-handling, elmah.mvc

I want to use elmah in mvc applicaion.
I installed elmah from nuget

```
PM> Install-Package Elmah.MVC -Version 2.1.2
```

I added following code to webConfig file:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
<system.web>
 <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>

 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.OracleErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah" applicationName="MyApp" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Now I type browser url http://localhost:56741/elmah.axd

I get following error

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made
> to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x8007000B)

please somebody help me

Comment: That is usually a 32bit/64bit issue. Have you tried "Any CPU" ? Check the platform target of your projects as well.

Comment: @SteveGreene I tried Any CPU, x86,x64 but not working

Comment: What happens if you browse http://localhost:56741/elmah instead of http://localhost:56741/elmah.axd?